# Can I farm Chlorophyte above ground level?

Tags: terraria

If I want to farm chlorophyte do I have to do it under ground level?
Because I tried doing it a few times above ground level but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Terraria Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Chlorophyte_Ore):

- It will only seed naturally in the Underground Jungle, but does not require Underground Jungle in order to spread.
- Chlorophyte can be seeded by the player in any underground biome, but requires a depth at least halfway between the Surface and the Cavern layer (halfway into the Underground layer and below).
- Chlorophyte can spread much more in the Cavern layer and below than it can above the Cavern layer